# Mootools - Need to edit name of dropdown to get value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, mootools

See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mxaB5/)

Trying to get the alerts to fire after the 3rd dropdown but they won't.
I am using these 3 dropdowns in a form.  The first and second dropdowns submit their values appropriately - the 3rd one does not - because it's not getting the correct name applied to the dropdown.

I can't figure out why the last alerts will not fire - so any input on why would be of great help.

I sprinkled in the alerts so that I know how far I am getting through the javascript, but the last couple alerts do not fire.

I'm a total javascript idiot.  The more I think I understand, the less I seem to be able to do - so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your goal is to ultimately get an event firing up upon a choice at level 3, simplify like so:

```
(function() {
    var level1 = document.getElements("div.style-sub-1"), level2 = document.getElements("div.style-sub-2");
    var beer = document.id("beerStyle");

    beer.addEvent("change", function() {
        level1.setStyle("display", "none");
        level2.setStyle("display", "none");

        var val = this.get("value");
        if (!val.length)
            return;

        document.id(this.get("value")).setStyle("display", "block");
    });

    // delegate the other selects
    $(document.body);
    document.body.addEvents({
        "change:relay(div.style-sub-1 select)": function() {
            // reset level 2
            level2.setStyle("display", "none");
            var val = this.get("value");

            if (!val.length)
                return;

            var target = document.id(val);
            if (target)
                target.setStyle("display", "block");        
        },
        "change:relay(div.style-sub-2 select)": function() {
            alert("You chose: " + this.get("value"));
        }
    });

})();
```

the problem is - if the level 3 has just 1 choice, which won't trigger a change - so you really ought to keep state of the last good breadcrumb you know of, eg, hybrid.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/mxaB5/2/

via a single event handler per select type that is delegated. i hope it gives you some ideas - you can ultimately work with just 2 functions to store whatever data you need.

part of you problem is that the 2nd level dropdowns can reference values that have no representation in the dom in the form of a div and a select.

Comment: Man have I got a lot to learn, but this did the trick! - Are there any good sources you know of where I can learn more about this stuff?  What would you recommend?  As you saw from my existing code - I'm a JS dummy - but would love to get to a level of comfort with it.

Comment: well - i would say, no.1 goal for you ought to be stepping back and looking at programming to patterns. you can already work the dom so now it's about changing your mentality a little and abstracting your tasks, grouping repeating ones in functions or methods or classes that can be reused and reused all over your app or across different apps. check the about mootools tag here on SO for some good links, also, google the Aaron Newton talk "programming to patterns with mootools" (IIRC), it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Is there a way to make this code work with 1.2.5?  I can't use 1.2.5.1(the 'more' features).   But this code doesn't work within the 1.2.5 library (UGH!!!). 
http://jsfiddle.net/mxaB5/7/
I looked in the Docs and it looks like 'relay' isn't an option for 1.2.5 - how would be the best way to approach this without using that?